# input text type alter height if exceed width size

Tags: html, css

Im not sure if this is a javascript fix or CSS Im happy with either, no jquery please.

The problem is that some of my input text value is larger than the width set to it. how can i auto size the height so that it continue to display the text in the next line?

```
<input type="text" value="Hi ssfgsdg dgd gdf bdf bdf bdfb fb fb fb fb fb" readonly class="lbl-txt">
```

output: Hi ssfgsdg dgd gdf bdf

```
.lbl-txt{
width: 250px;
height: auto;
white-space: normal;
overflow: hidden;
color: ghostwhite;
font-size: 20px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
border: none;
margin-left: 5px;
}
```

I need it to be Input Type text.

Comment: you set a fixed width ...

Comment: It has to be a fixed width but auto height

Comment: ah, it's not possible then

Answer (score 0):

> how can i auto size the height so that it continue to display the text in the next line?

You can't with an `<input>`.

Use a textarea insead, that is meant for multiline input: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

`<textarea name="...">default value</textarea>`